# shared pointer as variable in namespace: make sure there is no unexpected behavior

Tags: c++, class, reference, shared-ptr

```
class A 
{
    public:
         A(const std::shared_ptr<B> params_);
    private:
        const std::shared_ptr<B> params;
        void fun1();
};

A::A(const std::shared_ptr<B> params_)
:
params(params_)
{}

void A::fun1()
{
    calc::fun2(params);
}

namespace calc
{
    std::shared_ptr<B> params;
    void fun2(const std::shared_ptr<B> & params_)
    {
        calc::params = params_;
        //...
    }
}

int main()
{
    //create instance of A and call calc::fun2()
}
```

In the code above, class A holds a pointer to an object B. The namespace calc also needs access to the data of object 2. Is the above code safe if we think about dangling pointers/references? I currently debug a bigger program and want to make sure that the above code does not cause any form of undefined behavior/memory leaks.

Comment: `const std::shared_ptr<B> params;` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Why not?

Comment: What's wrong with just removing that `const`? Shared pointers ***share*** a resource and reference counting.

Comment: _"Why not?"_ Because `params = params_` .... You can't assign to `params` since it's `const`.

Comment: `const` members often lead to problems when it comes to implement assignment operators

Comment: @Simon OK you're editing the question as you go along. But your latest version is still incorrect (because of the const). You should post real code, not code written on the fly, much less error prone. It can be hard to tell the difference between typos and genuine mistakes.

Comment: You were right. I used a initialization list instead of the = assignment.

Comment: @Simon What's the instance of `A` used for in `main`? _"create instance of A and call `calc::fun2()`"_ We can't use the instance of `A` to call `calc::fun2()` since `A::fun1` is `private`. Why not present a program that compiles and does what you want, _then_ we can perhaps tell you if it's safe.

Comment: @TedLyngmo My real program depends on a bunch of external libraries. So I can not post real code. I just wanted to check if the above workflow of the references is *theoretically* safe and if there is an *obvious mistake*

Comment: @Simon Real code isn't necessary but a [mre] would make it a lot clearer. We wouldn't have to guess how you _theoretically_ call `calc::fun2` using `A::fun1` etc.

Comment: Why do you suspect there might be a dangling pointer/reference? The question kind of reads like "Here is some code I threw together; please test it for me." Consequentially, it's not likely to be of help to anyone in the future, because the chance of someone else throwing together the exact same code is extremely slim. Describing what you see as the potential problem could go a long way in mitigating these concerns (and it might help you refine your MRE).

Answer (score 0):

In the code as presented, there are no obvious dangling references. However, there's very little context provided.

If B would contain a shared_ptr to A, this could (depending on usage) create a cyclical dependency.

Comment: B is a struct and holds some double and integers, but no pointers or references.